# react-scripts build just hangs when encountering "Module not found" error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, build, react-scripts

During a CI pipeline build, I run an `npm run build` that eventually calls `react-scripts build`. I notice that this command just hangs and did not exit when a "Module not found" error occurred.

What can I do to make this kind of error fails immediately and not hangs until it times out?  I did not notice this problem happening for other kinds of error.

```
$ npm run build

> app@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Icon.svg' in 'C:\ProjectA\app\src\modules\module1\pages\page1\assets'

|
```

**Additional information** 
NodeJS version: 16.14.1 
npm version: 8.5.0 
react-scripts version: 5.0.0 
CI: Azure DevOps